something is blocking the streaming print command - it appears when I end the bot
I am developing a Discord AI Chatbot and I test step by step
I have a print command in a streaming response that works but doesnt print while the bot runs, only shows when I stop the bot script
main.py
from discord.ext import commands
from typing import Literal
import discord
import json

class Client(commands.Bot):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(command_prefix='.', intents=discord.Intents().all())
    self.cogslist = ['Cogs.tickets', 'Cogs.groqy']

  async def on_ready(self):
    print("\nmain:on_ready: Logged in as " + self.user.name)
    synced = await self.tree.sync()
    print("\nmain:on_ready: Slash CMDs Synced "+ str(len(synced)) + " Commands")

  async def setup_hook(self):
    for ext in self.cogslist:
      await self.load_extension(ext)

with open('config.json', 'r') as f: 
  TOKEN = json.load(f)['TOKEN']
  if TOKEN:
    print("\nmain: Bot Token Found")

client = Client()

@client.tree.command(name="reload", description="Reloads a Cog Class")
async def reload(interaction: discord.Interaction, cog:Literal["Tickets","Groqy"]):
    await client.reload_extension(f"Cogs.{cog.lower()}")
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"\nSuccessfully reloaded **{cog}.py**\n", ephemeral=True) 
    print(f"\nmain:command:reload: Successfully reloaded **{cog}.py**\n")

client.run(TOKEN)


groqy.py (discord cog)
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord import ui
import datetime
import discord
from libs.groqZen import main
from typing import Literal
class groqy(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client: commands.Bot):
        print("\nmain:cog:groqy: loaded")
        self.client = client

    @app_commands.command(name="groqy", description="use groqy fast!")
    async def groqy(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, message:Literal["Test Groqy","Groqy say hi!"]):
        print("\nmain:command:groqy: invoked")
        """
        This function invokes the main function in libs/groqZen and prints the deltas that are returned.
        
        Args:
            interaction (discord.Interaction): The interaction object that invoked the function.
            selection (str): The selection made by the user in the dropdown menu.
        """
        await interaction.response.send_message(content="Loading...", ephemeral=True)
        print(f"\nmain:command:groqy: Loading message sent")
        message_sent = await interaction.original_response()
        print(message_sent)
        
        async for delta in main(message):
            print(delta, end="")
        #await interaction.followup.edit_message(message_id=message_sent.id,content="Done!")
        await message_sent.edit(content="Done!")

and the groqZen.py the groq code
import asyncio
import os
from groq import AsyncGroq
from dotenv import load_dotenv

async def main(message):
    load_dotenv()
    groq_api_key = os.getenv("GROQ_API_KEY")
    client = AsyncGroq(api_key=groq_api_key)
    
    stream = await client.chat.completions.create(
        #
        # Required parameters
        #
        messages=[
            # Set an optional system message. This sets the behavior of the
            # assistant and can be used to provide specific instructions for
            # how it should behave throughout the conversation.
            {
                "role": "system",
                "content": "you are Groqy Fast; a fast AI chatbot based on Groq fast inference.",
            },
            # Set a user message for the assistant to respond to.
            {
                "role": "user",
                "content": message,
            }
        ],

        # The language model which will generate the completion.
        model="llama3-8b-8192",

        #
        # Optional parameters
        #

        # Controls randomness: lowering results in less random completions.
        # As the temperature approaches zero, the model will become
        # deterministic and repetitive.
        temperature=0.5,

        # The maximum number of tokens to generate. Requests can use up to
        # 2048 tokens shared between prompt and completion.
        max_tokens=1024,

        # Controls diversity via nucleus sampling: 0.5 means half of all
        # likelihood-weighted options are considered.
        top_p=1,

        # A stop sequence is a predefined or user-specified text string that
        # signals an AI to stop generating content, ensuring its responses
        # remain focused and concise. Examples include punctuation marks and
        # markers like "[end]".
        stop=None,

        # If set, partial message deltas will be sent.
        stream=True,
    )

    # Print the incremental deltas returned by the LLM.
    async for chunk in stream:
        #print(chunk.choices[0].delta.content, end="")
        yield chunk.choices[0].delta.content


I want to print the streaming output but it doesnt print unless I stop the bot script

Please, create a MRE and attach the console output.

it was a print flush issue:
changing:
print(delta, end="")
to
print(delta, end="", flush=True)
fixed it
thats why when the response from groq had a \n character it displayed partial response in termnial!
